# How do I restore default terminal command for Notifications on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, notifications

On Yosemite I disabled notifications with the following terminal command:

```
cd `getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR`
rm -rf com.apple.notificationcenter
killall usernoted; killall NotificationCenter
```

Does anyone know what I need to type to restore the original default notification setting?

Answer (score 1):

What you've done here is delete the entire Notification Center database, not simply disable Notification Center. You will need to restore this container, preferably from a backup. Alternatively, you can reinstall OS X.

Comment: Yikes!!!!!To do reinstall OS X, do I need to reformat my hard drive or can I just reinstall OS 10 on top of what I have?